# Python 3 Escaping Quotes in System Calls

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert new lines in a text file to "\n" characters in a string by running an Awk command using os.system:

```
awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' /tmp/file
```

My problem is that escaping the quotes is not working:

```
$ replace = "awk '{printf \"%s\\n\", $0}' /tmp/file"
$ print(replace)
awk '{printf "%s\n", $0}' /tmp/file
```

I've tried using shlex as well:

```
$ import shlex
$ line = "awk '{printf \"%s\\n\", $0}'"
$ lexer = shlex.shlex(line, posix=True)
$ lexer.escapedquotes = "'\""
$ mystring = ','.join(lexer)
$ print(mystring)
awk,{printf "%s\n", $0}
```

I either need to know how to run this awk command with Python or how to convert carriage returns/new lines in a file to "\n" in a string.

EDIT: Here's an example file:

```
oneline
twoline

threeline
```

A method should return the following from this file:

```
oneline\ntwoline\n\nthreeline
```

Comment: this won't work? `replace = "awk '{printf \"%s\\\\n\", $0}' /tmp/file"`

Comment: that worked...i stopped at 3 backslashes...didn't think a fourth one would do any good :)

Comment: Do you want to replace an end of line with the single character `'\n'` (`'\0a'`) or with the two characters`'\\'` `'n'` ('\x5d\x6e')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in that case you can use raw prefix + triple quoting:

```
s = r"""awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' /tmp/file"""
print(s)
```

result:

```
awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' /tmp/file
```

So `os.system(s)` works.

in pure python, replace newline by literal `\n` (adapted from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729099/dos2unix-not-working-when-trying-to-silence-command/49729239#49729239)):

```
with open(file1,"rb") as f:
   contents = f.read().replace(b"\n",b"\\n")
with open(file1+".bak","wb") as f:
   f.write(contents)
os.remove(file1)
os.rename(file1+".bak",file1)
```

Comment: Your pure python method doesn't concat the file...it just adds a bunch of "\n"'s wherever it should. Example file:
      asd
      ffd

Your method creates this:

      asd\n
      ffd\n
      \n

Where it should create this:

      asdffd\n

Comment: can you edit your question to see the input & expected output? because it's unclear in comments.

Comment: Added an example with expected output

Comment: thanks. In general, calling `awk` or `sed` from python isn't a very good idea because it makes your script non-portable and performs a system call, which breaks the chain of exception, when everything can be done even simpler in pure python.